# Seam Navigation Rule. Catch all invalid url and redirect to a 404 page

Tags: java, jboss7.x, seam2, faces-config, jboss-seam

I am using SEAM 2.3.0 (JBoss 7.1), trying to implement the following navigation logic:

For every *.xhtml that I don't catch in any page rule, forward to a 404.xhtml error page.

Something like this:

`<page view-id="/*.xhtml">
    <navigation>
        <redirect view-id="/404.xhtml" />
    </navigation>
</page>`

But it's not working

For all url that have a wrongly written extension then the 404 page will displayed due to:

`<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/404.xhtml</location>
</error-page>`

in the web.xml.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
    <location>/404.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```